# How to opencart 3.0.0.0 add external theme on localhost?

Tags: model, opencart, setting

I installed opencart 3.0.0.0. And then I put in external theme file front-end `catalog/view/theme/welldone_theme` in this location but I can not connect the admin stater setting for not visible and Waring error is:

> you do not have permission to default store theme

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- Older themes won't work with 3.0.  Is this theme twig-based?  If not, it won't work.
- There's a bug in the first release of 3.0 where you have to go to admin->system->users->user groups->administrator and edit it and save.

Comment: ok, 3.0 version won't work older themes. i tried to admin->system->users-> usergroups ->administrator-> access permission and modify permission selected all ->save but warring error display yet.